# Not able to close SNMP::Session

Tags: perl, snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I have created a SNMPv3 session using `SNMP:Session` as below:

```
Use SNMP;
$sess = new SNMP::Session(..);
$sess->close();
```

But I am not able to close this session using close function.
Please let me know if there is any other utility to close SNMP session.

Comment: You're creating the session incorrectly. Instead of `new`, use the `session` method, as described in the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SNMP#session---create-a-new-Net::SNMP-object): `my ($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session(...);`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Pls note that [ SNMP:session ] uses package SNMP while Net::SNMP->Session  uses package NET::SNMP.These two are entirely different way of creating session .

Comment: Oops, I read your question too quickly. There *is* no `close` method in SNMP::Session ([here's the correct documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/SNMP)). Since `$sess` is an object, I assume the session is closed when it's destroyed; if `$sess` is a lexical variable, that would be as soon as it goes out of scope.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Ok ,thank you !